# how i can create a buy Ehter

Tags: ether, wallets, dapps, coinbase

i have a question :

- how i can create a app to buy ether ?, i know how to create a Token sale but i dont know what api or what i need to buy ether directly

i see websites like coinbase to buy ether , but i really wanna know how that websites buy ether, i wanna deploy a dapp with buy ether directly from there, but i dont know what i need to do that , somebody can help me ? :(

thanks for read <3

Answer (score 1):

There are two points you have to consider: having Ether to sell and what do you accept as payment.

Basically your contract has to own Ether it can then sell. So you need to buy it from some marketplace and store in the contract. Then you probably want to take some assets from your customers and exchange them for Ethers from your contract - but what are such assets?

Your contract can only accept assets as Ethers or tokens - it can't accept any other types of assets. Accepting Ethers for Ethers doesn't sound reasonable so you'd need to accept tokens as payment, then you have to decide on which tokens and what is the exchange ratio and so on.

In the end you most likely don't want to try to start yet another exchange. Real exchanges basically take fiat and give back Ether but the regulations around those are very strict and complicated.

Comment: Hello ! thanks for comment , i wanna do something like this "So you need to buy it from some marketplace" , i wanna know how this markets buy the ether because i wanna programming something like that, but i dont know how to do it :(

Comment: I'm sorry but I really really really don't recommend you to try to start an exchange on your own. It's a serious and very demanding business

Answer (score 1):

Start off by creating a simple `faucet` dapp. So you can understand the fundamentals. Creating a huge platform like coinbase takes a lot of time and effort, but writing a smart contract that has the basic functionality of "buing Ether" is quite simple actually. But **do it on the testnet**, creating safe crypto systems or exchanges is super complicated.

But you gotta learn this fundamental stuff yourself

You can check out some books about Ethereum such as *Mastering Ethereum* by Andreas Antonopoulos, or some youtube/Udemy tutorials to help you with that.